# Relay connector exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

I want to know if it's possible to define a relay connector sender for a specific user/domain in exchange 2007.

For example :

All users -> default relay -> all domains

*.test.com -> test relay -> all domains

Thank's a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can for a single user, but you definitely can for an individual domain.

Within Organization Configuration, Hub Transport, Send Connectors you'll likely already have at least one send connection configured defining how your email is sent. If you have just one then the Address Space setting will likely be *.

To define a send connector for a specific domain that you want to be handled differently, simply create a new send connector, give it a name on the first page of the wizard. In Address Space click Add and set the address as "*.yourdomain.com". In Network Settings, define how you want it to send, eg via MX lookup for routed via particular smart hosts.

Once that has been added all mail for that specific domain will be routed via that send connector, while the remaining mail will continue to be routed by the existing one.

Update:
One way to do it (that I came across today) is to use a custom routing agent. I haven't done this myself so can't comment on how well it works, but this guide seems to explain the process http://blogs.technet.com/b/appssrv/archive/2009/08/26/how-to-control-routing-from-your-own-routing-agent.aspx or in addition there's third party apps which apparently can do it for you like http://www.servolutions.com/multisendcon.htm

Comment: I don't want to specify the destination domain but the sender domain. For example, all users from *.test.com use the test relay and the overs the default one.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find some links about this. It's not possible with the default installation.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/dc7976e5-a6e2-4269-a63a-b3f012208e59/determine-outbound-smtp-route-based-on-senders-email-domain